# Including Z in a logistic regression model with X, Y and XY

Tags: regression, logistic, interaction

Quick question, hope somebody could help me! I have a logistic regression model with dichotomous variables X, Y and interaction term XY. However, there is a third dichotomous variable Z that is also significant. I only discovered this afterwards, so my model was:

Dependent variable = e^(b0+b1X+b2Y+b3XY).

And I interpreted the odds ratios with this model by choosing the dichotomous variables to 1 and 0. How should I change the model and interpretation now that Z has to be added?

I mean that the variables X, Y, Z and the interaction between X and Y are significant. When I only put X, Y and XY in the model I can interpret the odds ratios when looking at the situations where X = 1, Y = 0 and reversely. When another dichotomous variable Z enters the equation, does it not become too complex to evaluate? Am I required to put it all in one equation and work with e^(b0+b1X+b2Y+b3XY+b4Z)? Thanks for the help :)

Kind regards,
Tom

Comment: I mean that the variables X, Y, Z and the interaction between X and Y are significant. When I only put X, Y and XY in the model I can interpret the odds ratios when looking at the situations where X = 1, Y = 0 and reversely. When another dichotomous variable Z enters the equation, does it not become too complex to evaluate? Am I required to put it all in one equation and work with e^(b0+b1X+b2Y+b3XY+b4Z)? Thanks for the help :)